# Stream memory leak in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, backend

Am working on a nodejs backend and I need to get the file types of a list of streams of files the user is uploading. Whenever I run the `getStreamFileTypes` function, the result is not correct, I might get a video file type of an image and vice versa with this error printed to the console:

```
(node:11868) MaxListnersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

How do I fix this? This is the code:

```
const getStreamFileTypes = async (streams) => {
  try {
    // get a list of detector promises
    const typePromises = streams.map(stream => {
      // pipe the stream content to detector
      // to emit file type
      miss.pipe(stream, detector, err => {
        if(err) {
          console.log('an error occured');
          throw err;
        }
      });
      // stream.pipe(detector).resume();
      // return dector filetypepromise that resolves
      // to the file type of the stream
      return detector.fileTypePromise()
        .then(filetype => {
          return { ...filetype, stream };
        })
        .catch(error => {
          throw UnknownError;
        });
    });
    // wait for all stream's filetypes to be detected
    const fileTypes = await Promise.all(typePromises);
    return fileTypes;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('error occured while getting stream types ', error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot pipe `miss` to multiple streams. Or what is `miss` ?

Comment: `miss` is the reference variable to the npm module `mississippi`. `detector` is the npm module `stream-file-types` and the variable `stream` is the user file streams